# How to find large cells in a Mathematica notebook?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

I occasionally end up with a notebook that is excessively slow in the front-end because of its size. Often it's some animation. How can I use Mathematica to find the large cell responsible for this?

Here's an [example notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/linear-estimation-scratch-oct.nb) where I ended up with this problem.

Comment: maybe something like `ReverseSortBy[Cells[EvaluationNotebook[], GeneratedCell -> True],  ByteCount@NotebookRead@# &]`?

Comment: You could try using ``ResourceFunction["NotebookCellData"][]`

Comment: Related question: [Notebook cells space on disk profiler](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87102/notebook-cells-space-on-disk-profiler/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
Map[Tooltip[#, ByteCount@NotebookRead@#] &] @
 TakeLargestBy[Cells[EvaluationNotebook[], GeneratedCell -> True], 
  ByteCount @ NotebookRead @ # &, 10]
```

[image]

Click on the button to go the target cell.

Answer (score 2):

`NotebookCellData` gives a slightly nicer formatted table. Looks like a single vector graphics can push 50MB, makes sense to Rasterize.

```
notebookCellData = 
  ResourceFunction["NotebookCellData", 
   ResourceSystemBase -> 
    "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/resourcesystem/api/1.0"];
Take[ReverseSortBy[
  notebookCellData[
   EvaluationNotebook[], {"CellByteCount"}], #CellByteCount &], 
 UpTo[5]]
```

[image]